# rails newbie: how to set before_filter function for several application_controllers?

Tags: controller

my application have two application controllers, one for consumer and the other for admin pages. each controller has it's own logic, but some of the code is the same.

for example I would like to set local before filter. consumer application_controller code is something like this:

```
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale    
  I18n.locale = :de
end
```

now, I would like the same code to be in the other application_controller, but don't want to duplicate it.

How can I share the code for both application controlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by creating a new module in lob directory, then include it in both application controllers.